# Redirecting /folder/ to /file.html in magento

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, magento-1.7

We published an article in the magazine with following url:

```
http://magnetic-sleep-machine.com/moves
```

Now we need to make sure when people put that URL they land to

```
https://magnetic-sleep-machine.com/moves.html
```

Please help me figure this out! .htaccess or use a magento (1.7) option?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to redirect using [magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9848/programmatically-301-redirect/9849#9849), but not sure if that's exactly what you want.

You could also try turning on multiviews, and let mod_negotiation take cure of fuzzy URL-file mapping, in your htaccess file:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^moves/?$ /moves.html [L,R=301]
```

Or using mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/moves/?$ /moves.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the way to do it using magento itself.

- created a new Page
- page link named as "moves"
- added javascript for redirect to body of the page
- next went to system>config>web>
- set Auto-redirect to Base URL to NO

Voila, it works now.